# Xcode: UIScrollView or TextView auto scrolling

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview

I would like to know if it is possible to make the scrollview or textview able to scroll from top to bottom automatically after pressing a button? And the speed of scrolling can it be controllable by users?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works well and you will be surprised how it works (especially the formula)
speed = distance / time

http://www.aaron.griffith.name/weblog/2011/02/23/scrolling-a-uiscrollview-programmatically/

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore. Do you have a new one?